# How can I toggle Handoff (Continuity) in Terminal on macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to enable/disable the Handoff setting from the command line?

Currently, I'm using macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and I know I can toggle it by going to Settings > General > "Allow Handoff" - but looking for an alternate way.

[image: Handoff toggle in settings]

Comment: There is a scritpt here, but it does not seem to work under 10.14: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12545/a-script-to-disable-handoff

Comment: It works! I need to test it more, but you @slhck should get the answer points for this one!  The supplied full bash scripts didn't work out-of-the-box, but the raw commands to update the useractivityd.plist work from this post: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12545/a-script-to-disable-handoff#responseChild139821 -- Didn't even have to log on/off to see the preference updated.

Comment: Good to know. Yeah, these bash scripts are not coded well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following commands should turn Handoff off:

```
sudo -u $(whoami) defaults write "$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist" ActivityAdvertisingAllowed -bool no
sudo -u $(whoami) defaults write "$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist" ActivityReceivingAllowed -bool no
```

To turn on again:

```
sudo -u $(whoami) defaults write "$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist" ActivityAdvertisingAllowed -bool yes
sudo -u $(whoami) defaults write "$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist" ActivityReceivingAllowed -bool yes
```

Source: [jamf.com](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/12545/a-script-to-disable-handoff#responseChild139821) – note that I have not verified the commands, but the OP claims them to be working.

Comment: Using these every day on macOS Mojave 10.14.3.  Thanks again!

Comment: "$HOME/Library/Preferences/ByHost/com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd.plist" does not exist on my fresh Mojave install, 10.14.5

Answer (score 5):

[@slhck's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1424095/680651) can be simplified to:

On:

```bsh
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd ActivityAdvertisingAllowed -bool yes
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd ActivityReceivingAllowed -bool yes
```

Off:

```bsh
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd ActivityAdvertisingAllowed -bool no
defaults -currentHost write com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd ActivityReceivingAllowed -bool no
```